# Trouble concatenating floats and strings in Python

Tags: python-3.x, concatenation

I'm using this code:

```
for each in x: 
            descrVar = descrVar + " " + df.iloc[counter,each]
```

to iterate through a table and concatenate cells into a variable. The problem is, some of the cells will be a `Nan`. As a result, I'm getting the following error:

```
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "numpy.float64") to str
```

I assume this means a `Nan` is a float64 and not a str.  Is there any way around this, such as forcing every cell to convert to a str?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An f-string will format your data as `str`.

```
for each in x:
    descrVar += f" {df.iloc[counter,each]}"
```